# htaccess not working on ubuntu , tried all options

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu

I have frusted doing all things given on web for htaccess get working on ubuntu. But I could not do it. Actually I want to run my `CodeIgniter` app on `LAMP`, its not production server. so in www directory, there could be multiple folders e.g.
www/punepchub

I access url `localhost/punepchub/support/` , it gives 404 error

I want to redirect above link  to `localhost/punepchub/index.php/support/` 
using `htaccess`, following are the contents of htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Where as above mentioned htaccess works perfect on wamp as well as lamp given by godaddy hosting, but it is not working on LAMP server setup on my local ubuntu 12.04 desktop machine
I think apache is not accessing the htaccess file.

I tried following but It didn't worked

1. I have installed lamp using `tasksel`
2. Enabled Rewrite module using command: `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
3. It displays the module in the list given by command: `sudo apache2ctl -M`
4. Changed `etc/apache2/sites-available/default` file with `AllowOverride All`, Also I did same in `etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`
5. I have `777` permissions for project folder and files

Also I am confused about Is there any need to create `virtual hosts`, as this is not production server.

Please help me I really don't know how resolve this issue now.

In advance many thanks

Comment: There's no need of adding virtual hosts to get htaccess working, though I recommend it. Do you have `Options +FollowSymLinks` and `RewriteEngine On` in that htaccess?

Comment: This question is a bit vague at the moment - can you edit and post an example of what you're trying to rewrite to what, and the rules that you currently have defined to achieve this?

Comment: I want to remove index.PHP from url using htaccess

Comment: Show us your .htaccess you're trying to use. Give examples of incoming (from visitors) URIs and what you're trying to remap them to. Show some that do work and some that don't.

Comment: hello all, I have updated my question with links properly and htaccess file contents, I looking forward to hear you friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /punepchub/
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /punepchub/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: hello I have tried this but didn't worked, I think that apache is not reading my htaccess file. I think there is some other issue, please help

Comment: In order to see if your .htaccess works, create a simple rule to redirect to www.google.com when you access your site.